# Set back date when creating posts in Wordpress - current_time()

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to somehow setback the date of the current_time function in wordpress?

Right now i am using it like this:

```
$time = current_time('mysql');
```

I would like to get the same year, month and time.. but set back the day with for example 2.

Any ideas guys? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function days_ago($days, $type, $gmt=0) {
    $time = $gmt? time() : time() + ( get_option('gmt_offset')*3600 );
    $d = explode('-', date('H-i-s-n-j', $time));
    $time = mktime($d[0], $d[1], $d[2], $d[3], $d[4]-$days);
    return $type=='mysql'? gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) : $time;
}
```

It works just like current_time(), except that you pass it a number of days:

```
$time = days_ago(2, 'mysql');
```

Note that if you didn't need the `$type` and `$gmt` options that current_time() provides, you could use this instead:

```
function days_ago($days) {
    $d = explode('-', date('H-i-s-n-j'));
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($d[0], $d[1], $d[2], $d[3], $d[4]-$days));
}

$time = days_ago(2);
```